# Select only a text of cell in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

in a datagridview I want to select only the text of the cell and not the whole cell

if I put

```
Datagridview.CurrentRow.Cells.[Datagridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Selected=true;
```

the entire cell is selected

is there a way to select only the text of the cell like a vb6

```
Datagridview.SelStart=0
Datagridview.SelLength=Len(Datagridview.Text)
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me, after adding a new row i want to edit the 2nd column of the row being added.
at same time the value of the cell is being highlighted. Hope this helps"

```
        DataGridViewCell cellQty = dgvBundle.Rows[dgvBundle.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1];
        dgvBundle.CurrentCell = cellQty;            
        dgvBundle.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Selected = true;
        dgvBundle.BeginEdit(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

BeginEdit will select everything in the cell but you can specify the start and length of selection by:

```
        ((TextBox)dgv.EditingControl).SelectionStart = 0;
        ((TextBox)dgv.EditingControl).SelectionLength = 3;
```

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer that does not deserve a down vote.  In fact, after canceling a cell edit for invalid data (in CellValidating), it's probably the only way to achieve the desired effect of selecting all text in the errant cell.  But I would use ((TextBox)dgv.EditingControl).SelectAll() unless I was trying to select only a portion of the text.

Comment: Good. Exactly I was looking for !!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by calling `BeginEdit()` method for the `DataGridView` control. It will start edit mode for the selected cell. You can also set the `EditMode` of the `DataGridView` control:

```
//set selected cell as you showed in your question
datagridview1.CurrentRow.Cells.[Datagridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Selected=true;

//call BeginEdit with true argument which will select all text within the cell
dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);

//optionally set the EditMode before you call BeginEdit
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current cell programmatically:

`string msg = String.Format("Row: {0}, Column: {1}",
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex,
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex);
 MessageBox.Show(msg, "Current Cell");`

Comment: The OP wants to *select* the text inside the cell (without selecting the whole cell), not get the current cell.